# overheating thosiba m840 radeon 7500M/7600M ubuntu 14.04

Tags: overheating

i newbie ubuntu 14.04. and i have problem overheating in my laptop. please help me to slove it. i use laptop thosiba satelite m840 series with Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series. please

Answer (score 0):

Laptops overheating is not a problem specific tu Ubuntu. It can happens with Windows 7/8/8.1/10.

If your toshiba satelite m840 is not under warranty anymore, you can try to open it carefully and using a air spray bottle, try to remove dust as much as possible, specially on the CPU fan and cooler below. Samething with the GPU fan and cooler below.

This should help to gain an appreciable difference in degrees.

Please take note that a battery charging is heating also.

Comment: Moreover I could see in your model description that it should be equipped  with a Intel i7 and a HD 7670M : have a look at this article : http://goo.gl/qQBNCg